# instance variables

Tags: python, function, variables, arguments, instance

I was wondering if it is possible to create a function foo in python so that

```
def calulate (self, input):
    input = #some stuff

def foo2(self):
    self.calculate(self.var1)
    self.calculate(self.var2)
```

or do you have to do this

```
def calculation(self):
    output=#some stuff
    return output
def foovar1(self):
    self.var1=self.calculation()
    self.var2=self.calculation()
```

I really don't want to have to do this because it would mean creating many more functions

Comment: Your two variants differ quite a lot, I don't get it. :/

Comment: I think you should describe in words what you want these snippets to do.

Comment: @unwind no they do not, just used different names for some dumb reason

Comment: @mgilson and unwind done!! sorry about that

Comment: the word "self" is usually associated with CLASS METHODS, but you talk about functions. How's that, exactely?

Comment: sorry i meant class methods :S

Comment: @heltonbiker: you mean instance methods, not class methods. Class methods tend to have `cls`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, you can mutate function arguments, but you can't rebind them in the caller's scope directly.  You could pass the instance member name:

```
def foo(self, inputname):
    setattr(self, inputname, #some stuff)

def foo2(self):
    self.foo('var1')
    self.foo('var2')
```

Alternately, if `self.var1` is a mutable object e.g. a list you could write:

```
def foo (self, input):
    input[:] = #some stuff

def foo2(self):
    self.foo(self.var1)
    self.foo(self.var2)
```

This works because you're mutating the list object (by assigning to a full slice) rather than rebinding it (a bare `=`).

Comment: @WasiqKashkari when you write `input[:] = something` you're modifying the object that the name `input` refers to; when you write `input = something` you're just rebinding the name `input` to refer to `something`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to have a specially crafted container.

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
```

and then use it in another class:

```
def foo(self, container):
    container.value = ...

def foo2(self):
    self.foo(self.var1)
    self.foo(self.var2)
```